# Spark running on EMR sporadically fails when writing to S3 with 403

Tags: amazon-s3, pyspark, amazon-emr

I have a spark job that runs on AWS EMR. The job does some data processing and writes the dataframe to s3 as a csv.

The job sporadically fails, while writing to s3 and throws a 403. I am almost certain that this is not an issue with the permissions as the job completes successfully almost 70% of the time and writes the output to s3 with no problem, but every now and then I get this

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/sparkProcessor/controller.py", line 58, in <module>
    processor.process()
  File "/home/sparkProcessor/processor.py", line 32, in process
    self.write_outputs(df1, df2, df3)
  File "/home/sparkProcessor/processor.py", line 168, in write_outputs
    df1.coalesce(1).write.csv(self.configurations['OUTPUT_DIRECTORY'] + "/" + dir_name+ "/output", mode="overwrite", header="true")
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py", line 931, in csv
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1257, in __call__
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 63, in deco
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 328, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o199.csv.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted.
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.write(FileFormatWriter.scala:198)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.run(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:159)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:104)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:102)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.doExecute(commands.scala:122)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:131)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:156)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:152)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:80)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:80)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter$$anonfun$runCommand$1.apply(DataFrameWriter.scala:676)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter$$anonfun$runCommand$1.apply(DataFrameWriter.scala:676)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1.apply(SQLExecution.scala:78)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:125)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:73)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:676)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveToV1Source(DataFrameWriter.scala:285)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:271)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:229)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.csv(DataFrameWriter.scala:664)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: s3a://sparkOutputBucket/output/_temporary/0/task_20200402173032_0032_m_000000/part-00000-47cc7efd-8dfe-4d5c-8e20-c5b3ab08278b-c000.csv: getFileStatus on s3a://sparkOutputBucket/output/_temporary/0/task_20200402173032_0032_m_000000/part-00000-47cc7efd-8dfe-4d5c-8e20-c5b3ab08278b-c000.csv: com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Forbidden (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: 403 Forbidden; Request ID: <request ID>; S3 Extended Request ID: <request ID>), S3 Extended Request ID: <Request ID>
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AUtils.translateException(S3AUtils.java:158)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AUtils.translateException(S3AUtils.java:101)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.getFileStatus(S3AFileSystem.java:1568)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.innerRename(S3AFileSystem.java:707)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.rename(S3AFileSystem.java:662)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter.mergePaths(FileOutputCommitter.java:457)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter.mergePaths(FileOutputCommitter.java:471)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter.commitJobInternal(FileOutputCommitter.java:388)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter.commitJob(FileOutputCommitter.java:360)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.DirectFileOutputCommitter.commitJob(DirectFileOutputCommitter.java:111)
    at org.apache.spark.internal.io.HadoopMapReduceCommitProtocol.commitJob(HadoopMapReduceCommitProtocol.scala:166)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.write(FileFormatWriter.scala:187)
    ... 33 more
Caused by: com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Forbidden (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: 403 Forbidden; Request ID: <Request ID>; S3 Extended Request ID: <Request ID>), S3 Extended Request ID: <Request ID>
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1712)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:1367)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1113)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:770)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:744)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:726)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.access$500(AmazonHttpClient.java:686)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:668)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:532)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:512)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:4921)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:4867)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.getObjectMetadata(AmazonS3Client.java:1320)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.getObjectMetadata(AmazonS3Client.java:1294)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.getObjectMetadata(S3AFileSystem.java:904)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.getFileStatus(S3AFileSystem.java:1553)
    ... 42 more
```

I looked online to see if someone else has had this issue but with no success. The closest I got was one thread where they were suggesting that this may have to do with s3a usage, however no suggestion was made on how to fix this.

Will really appreciate if someone can help with this.
Thank you!

P.S it seems like the getFileStatus permission is not satisfied, yet again 70% of the time this is not triggered, also I dont see any getFileStatus permissions for s3 role anyways.

Comment: You should try switching to s3. It’s not recommended for use s3a/n in emr I believe.

Comment: Yup. Seems like switching to s3 did the trick. Wonder why is this the solution though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-plan-file-systems.html

Note
The s3a protocol is not supported. We suggest you use s3 in place of s3a.

Comment: Thanks for sharing that documentation!